# displaying the battery status visually in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

Can I display the battery status in angularjs with ionic Framework visually, not with numbers?
The dependence `$cordovaBatteryStatus` of `ngCordova` shows only with numbers:
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/batteryStatus/

How can I display the status as shown in the following picture?

[image]

Comment: IMO convert the number into a percentage and use with css accordingly.

Comment: You may want to look at the [HTML5 progress element](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/). It's a pretty simple way to turn your 0-100 number into a horizontal bar - beyond that you just have to add some background images.